# API (total restrictions): Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following Error in Google Play before app publish.
Can You help how to resolve it ? Maybe I should update some libs ?

Interface API (total restrictions): Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:416)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2079)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2066)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.OptionalMethod.getPublicMethod(OptionalMethod.java:164)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.OptionalMethod.getMethod(OptionalMethod.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.OptionalMethod.invokeOptional(OptionalMethod.java:66)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.OptionalMethod.invokeOptionalWithoutCheckedException(OptionalMethod.java:86)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(AndroidPlatform.java:122)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:314)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:129)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:86)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score -1):

Logcat implies that you are using a non sdk api, according to docs https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Comment: How can I change this non-sdk api for another ? I  have no idea where this non-sdk is used in my app...

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet... I am not in rush because it don't cause any errors in my app. Do you have same issue ?

Comment: @shayan I am also getting this issue. How to resolved this? My compileSdkVersion - 29

Comment: i resolved this after updat okhttp library 4.9.1

Comment: @mikcad Any fixes you found ?

Please check :    https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3129

Version 3.12.9¶
2020-02-24

Fix: Don’t crash on Android 11 due to use of restricted methods. This prevents a crash with the exception, “Expected Android API level 21+ but was 29”.

So I think you need to updated okhttp vesrion to 3.12.9 or more